# EF6 Lazy Load a Class Property (string)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I use EF6's fluent API configuration to manage my domain/data mappings.

In one of my classes, I want to add two large string properties that contain a base64 image for signatures.  This exists in the domain and in the database.

But, I want to ignore those two fields, *until I need them.*  Not ignore outright (which is easy enough), but specifically lazy load those two string properties.

Can I do this "natively" via EF6 configuration, or will I have to handle those two fields manually?

Some code for good measure (doesn't feel like a real question without it...)

```
class Session {

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CaseID {get;set;}
    public int ProviderID {get;set;}
    public int ServiceID {get;set;}

    public DateTime Start {get;set;}
    public DateTime End {get;set;}

    // lazy load these two fields??
    public string ParentSignatureBase64 {get;set;}
    public string ProviderSignatureBase64 {get;set;}

    public virtual Case Case {get;set;}
    public virtual Provider Provider {get;set;}
    public virtual Service Service {get;set;}
}

CREATE TABLE dbo.Sessions (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1),
    CaseID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Cases (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ProviderID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Providers (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ServiceID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Services (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,

    SessionStartDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    SessionEndDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL,

    SessionParentSignatureBase64 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    SessionProviderSignatureBase64 NVARCHAR(MAX)
);



var s = modelBuilder.Entity<Session>();
s.Property(x => x.Start).HasColumnName("SessionStartDate");
s.Property(x => x.End).HasColumnName("SessionEndDate");
s.Property(x => x.ParentSignatureBase64)
    .HasColumnName("SessionParentSignatureBase64")
    .LazyLoad()   <-------- LIKE THIS??!?!?
s.Property(x => x.ProviderSignatureBase64)
    .HasColumnName("SessionProviderSignatureBase64")
    .LazyLoad()   <-------- LIKE THIS??!?!?
```

Comment: EF 6 doesn't provide a way to lazy-load primitives. Upon querying, you can use `Select(x => new Session { ... })` and fill all the properties except `ProviderSignatureBase64`. Then, when you *do* need that data, you'll have to consult your `dbContext` again (either directly or via some abstraction) and use `dbContext.Entry(yourSession).Property("ProviderSignatureBase64").CurrentValue` (same for your other property)

Comment: @haim770 - thanks, I had suspected as much but was hoping I was missing something.  If you want to throw it in an answer I'll upvote it.